# How to use Distinct for this select query in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, distinct

I have following query:

```
var query = from product in SH_Products
        from product_group in SH_ProductGroups_Products.Where(c=>c.ProductID == product.ID)
        from manufacturer in SH_Manufacturers.Where(c=>c.ID == product.ManufactureID)   
        from attributeOption_product in SH_AttributeOptions_Products.Where(c=>c.ProductID == product.ID).DefaultIfEmpty()
        where !product.IsDeleted
        && !product_group.IsDeleted
        && !manufacturer.IsDeleted
        && product.Status != 0  
        select new
        {
            product.ID,   
            ProductGroupID = product_group.ProductGroupID,
            AttributeOptionID = (int?)attributeOption_product.AttributeOptionsID,
            product.ManufacturerID
        };
query.Distinct().Dump();
```

Below is the sample output:

```
ID    ProductGroupID    AttributeOptionID    ManufacturerID
1     1                 75                   1
1     1                 76                   1
2     3                 17                   2
3     2                 3                    1
4     1                 NULL                 1
```

As you see, we have 2 record with `ID = 1`, and I don't wanna this, how I can remove this one?

I wrote this query for filtering section of my project.
I have filtering by `ProductGroupID`, `AttributeOptionID`, `ManufacturerID`, all of them are multi-select-able !

thanks !

Comment: Not an answer, but you you should use join syntax rather than id=id. Better still, use navigation properties. If you don't want duplicates, you should remove `AttributeOptionID` from the results.

Comment: thanks, I know if I remove 'AttributeOptionID', the 'Distinct' will work, but I need that !

Comment: You can use the other overload of Distinct extension method which asks for an EqualityComparer

Comment: If you need `AttributeOptionID` *and* distinct product ids you need a different shape of the output. What do you propose?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, you can use the other overload of `Distinct` extension method which asks for an `EqualityComparer`.

Or another way you can use

```
query.GroupBy(item => item.ID).Select(grp => grp.First())...
```

instead of

```
query.Distinct()...
```

Please do not forget that the output will not contain the second record in your sample output.

If the key of your records is not only `ID` but `ID` and `ProductGroupID` instead, usage can be

```
query.GroupBy(item => new {item.ID, item.ProductGroupId} ).Select(grp => grp.First())...
```

Comment: That way is totally true, I don't know that ability in LINQ, thanks! but as you said, I have no access to some of records in output and I don't wanna lose any record. I found a solution with creating view and using `FULL JOIN` in `SQL`.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Then omitting `.Select(grp => grp.First())` part you have groups. There are four groups with keys 1,2,3 and 4. First group has 2 records and the others one each.